# where is pip i cant find it

Tags: python, pip

hi i find out pip is installed on python 3.4 or higher. my python version is **3.8.5** but every time i type `pip --version` in Command Prompt its contains error what can i do?
here's the error:

```
'pip--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and in python is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

Comment: Try `pip --version` (space between `pip` and `--version`). If that doesn't work try `python3 -m pip --version`.

Comment: Look at what you typed: you need a space between the command and the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to type `pip --version`.

If this doesn't work then I guess you forget to check   **Add Python 3.8.x to PATH**
while installing. In that case just reinstall python.

Comment: i typed **pip --version** on cmd but because this is my first question on this site i did not know i have to type codes exactly what i typed here. anyway my point is i typed pip --version

Comment: Do one thing, go to cmd and type `python` followed by enter. Then in the python shell type ```import pip```. If that doesn't give you an error then that means pip is installed on your system but in case you do get an error then I would advice you to reinstall python and do check ```Add Python 3.8.x to PATH``` while installing.

Comment: i just uninstall python and reinstall it but when i type **pip --version** its still get me the fetal error and i try to install pip see what happend:

Comment: C:\Users\Downloads>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1.1
Successfully installed pip-20.1.1

C:\Users\Downloads>pip --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What happend when I asked you to type ```import pip``` in python shell. What error did it give?  Here is a link to correctly install python on your system. https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/python_installation/

Comment: i import pip without any error and i reinstall it and check Add Python 3.8.x to PATH while installing but still not working :|

Comment: if import pip is working without any error then that means pip is present on your system. I would suggest you further search on stack overflow and on youtube. Someone else surely must have encountered the same problem.

Comment: Also, manually check if pip is there by going to the path ```C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip``` and once try using the command  ```python -m pip --version```. Keep in mind there is a space before " - " and '' -- ".

Comment: dear friend i uninstall all of my pythons and scripts(where i find the **pip.exe**) and i reinstalled python and instead of choosing **install now** in installing python i choosed customize and checked all of option and set the directory and i now see its worked thank you.

Comment: well I have never followed that approach to install python. But glad to hear that your problem is finally resolved. Keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`pip3 --version`

What output do you get from this?

Comment: pip3 --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your  `pip` and `python` path on windows.

To set it follow the above link
https://youtu.be/UTUlp6L2zkw